# Regenerate ASP SHA1 salt / hash with PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, hash

We have a client with several thousand legacy password hashes, that they'd like us to be able to verify / match in order to move these logins to more modern security considerations.

The hashes are SHA1-like (hexadecimal and 40 chars), and were generated in ASP.NET. We have a few test cases that have the plaintext password, the base64-encoded salt, and the base64-encoded hash - and we need to be able to reproduce the hash based on the given password and salt.

I've been using https://forums.asp.net/p/1336657/2899172.aspx as a reference to write a PHP script to reproduce the hash. Here's the snippet I'm trying to rewrite directly:

```
public string EncodePassword(string pass, string saltBase64)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
    byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(saltBase64);
    byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);
    HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1");
    byte[] inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
}
```

It seems straightforward - get a byte array of the password, base64-decode the salt, concatenate them, and run them through SHA1. I feel like I'm 90% of the way there, but I can't match the provided hash successfully, no matter what variants I try!

I suspect that my attempt at reproducing `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes` is the problem - `unpack` probably isn't equivalent. But after an hour or so of searching I can't find any way to get closer. Not being an ASP developer, I'm sure there's some nuance I'm missing - can anyone point out where this is going wrong?

Here's my test output code:

```
$test = [
    'plaintext' => 'overthis2:)',
    'salt' => '7LeJR68EGhBgaE7EYgL/gg==',
    'hash' => 'g54KVV4Wj5smOyXHOReyWnTnGDc='
];
$algos = [ 'sha1', 'ripemd160', 'tiger160,3', 'tiger160,4', 'haval160,3', 'haval160,4', 'haval160,5' ];
$raw = implode( '', unpack( "H*", $test['plaintext'] ) ) . base64_decode( $test['salt'] );

echo 'Plaintext:     ' . $test['plaintext'] . "\n";
echo 'Salt:          ' . $test['salt'] . "\n";
echo 'Raw:           ' . $raw . "\n\n";
echo 'Saved hash:    ' . $test['hash'] . "\n";
echo 'Decoded:       ' . bin2hex( base64_decode( $test['hash'] ) ) . "\n\n";

foreach ( $algos as $algo ) {
    echo str_pad( $algo . ':' , 15, ' ' ) . hash( $algo, $raw ) . "\n";
}
```

Here's the result it gets - none of the hashes match the provided:

```
Plaintext:     overthis2:)
Salt:          7LeJR68EGhBgaE7EYgL/gg==
Raw:           6f76657274686973323a29췉G�`hN�b��

Saved hash:    g54KVV4Wj5smOyXHOReyWnTnGDc=
Decoded:       839e0a555e168f9b263b25c73917b25a74e71837

sha1:          d0b448e50d81e6a42601ebcc8e7aa07423d12210
ripemd160:     4359afa37173388db43c47db5188cf5cc47f30d9
tiger160,3:    c2e22500127cef7141077049e9bda7747e0b298d
tiger160,4:    e03fc57f1d9259cd650aab3682cf54609a30d62b
haval160,3:    437838726fc63fb15969e1c5f0b34dc7f404cabc
haval160,4:    ec5cb7e38fe28534b65d25fabf756113c9e563d6
haval160,5:    48551660bbc519bb7db8d595556f4f167eeec749
```

Comment: Because it is a hash you'll not be able to replicate. What you can do is setup the table to hold another column, check to see if they have a new hash. If not, check for no hash or an old hash and then create a new hash w/ `password_hash()`.

Comment: @JayBlanchard it should produce the same hash for the given inputs (if correct), right? SHA1-ing `test` will always give  `a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3`. See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31880/142141)

Comment: @JayBlanchard thanks for the input, but that's not true - SHA1 is a one-to-one conversion, the same string always produces the same hash. I'm just missing a component of how ASP.NET creates the pre-hashed password / salt. Can you give any insight into what I'm missing?

Comment: You're correct - sha1 to sha1 does produce the same thing. I should have been clearer because to me a hash is produced with a salt. Quick research reveals that others have failed to be able to produce this as well.

Comment: I think you have the salt in the end with PHP and ASP.NET puts it in the front

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET code handles the password as UTF16LE string (`Encoding.Unicode`), so every character is 16 bits wide. This means that in this case every other byte is zero in that part.

You also have salt and password the wrong way around and there is no need to unpack anything, the .NET code doesn't use hex values, rather raw bytes.

Make this change and you'll get the same hash value:

```
$raw = base64_decode( $test['salt'] ).implode("\0", str_split($test['plaintext']))."\0";
```

This simply takes the salt, decodes it, then it converts the password into UTF16 by adding a zero byte after every character and that's it.

Comment: This indeed solved my issue perfectly - thanks so much!